# When a row is added to the table, the C# program notifies

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need my C# program to know that when a new row is added to the "alerts" table, it writes a message box saying "Alert" basically I need a new row to come in that table, so the C# program will tell you soon!

Comment: Can you please post what you tried so far?

Comment: I already researched this but I think I have to do a row added in C #, I have a trigger in SQL that whenever the data passes the values ​​in the table put in the table "alerts" but I don't know how to do this part in C#

Comment: I think is much easier to just create single procedure in SQL Server. Procedure will have 2 steps, 1st to insert data into table and 2nd to set output variable to `@@ROWCOUNT`. Then in C# test output variable with one simple `IF`. If `@@ROWCOUNT` is 0, you not inserted a row. If you get 1 or more for result, you inserted that many row/s into table.
If you want, I can write you a procedure, just replace your tables and column names.